# MySQLdb library cannot find image

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use `MySQLdb` library.

I have install the library using `pip install mysqlclient`

When running: `import MySQLdb as db` I have the following error:

```
import MySQLdb as db
  File "/Users/Solal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Solal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Solal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

That's all the files I have in my `MySQLdb` repo:

```
constants
__pycache__
converters.py
_exceptions.py
cursors.py
_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
release.py
compat.py
times.py
connections.py
```

Also I have no folder `mysql` in `/usr/local/opt`

I have found online a fix as follow: 
`sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.10/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

However I have nothing in my `/usr/local/Cellar/` folder

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to make it work only by running:

`brew install mysql`